# flutter firebase realtime database different order on different devices

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hello i am making an application with flutter firebase realtime database.

players object firebase console is sorted like this:

```
players:
    HRbRK8VwoPd1E955hbxOhtziapg1:true
    MHvToO7l8wYFGpCyg8PWU7WNCRx2:true
```

when i get it in android simulator with flutter it is sorted like this:

```
players:
    MHvToO7l8wYFGpCyg8PWU7WNCRx2:true
    HRbRK8VwoPd1E955hbxOhtziapg1:true
```

when i get it in ios simulator with flutter it is sorted like this:

```
players:
    HRbRK8VwoPd1E955hbxOhtziapg1:true
    MHvToO7l8wYFGpCyg8PWU7WNCRx2:true
```

same code same json object but why is it sorted differently in android and ios simulators?

I call it like this in fluttur:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("rooms/test/players").get();
```

Comment: Basic answer below. If that doesn't answer your question, edit your question to show how you actually retrieve and process the results - as a single `get()` call is not enough to determine what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the keys in a JSON object is not guaranteed, and may indeed differ between platforms or even invocations on the same platform.

If you want a consistent order, you have to either request and process them from Firebase in that order (looping over the `children` or the result snapshot), or (re)order the players in your client-side code.